# Has the Catholic Church ever considered substitution of the "Peace Be With You" salutations in the Liturgy?

Tags: catholicism, liturgy, mass, spiritual-gifts, peace

The prayer for peace and the wishing of peace to one another are closely knitted into the fabric of Christianity. The practice definitely traces its origin to the Old Testament, and it has been reinforced by the Gloria sung by the angels at the Nativity, the Lord's own peace messages, his exhortation to the disciples to be the messengers of peace, etc.  One can definitely make out that peace was one of the main concerns of the Jews as well as early Christians who had always been fighting external forces.

But in the modern world, the Gifts of the Holy Spirit, including the Fear of God, Discernment, Wisdom and Knowledge, stand at equal footing. One is therefore inclined to conclude that the wishing of peace which occurs many times during the liturgy could perhaps be replaced with wishing for the Gifts of the Holy Spirit.

**My question therefore is**: Has the Catholic Church ever considered replacing the "Peace Be With You" salutations in the liturgy with a wish for the Gifts of the Holy Spirit?

Comment: "in the modern world" Has something changed where this wasn't true before?

Comment: Obviously. In the past, aggression and colonisation by the powerful kingdoms was more of a rule than an exception. In the modern world, we have anti-war treaties and international co- operation. Take the case of Japan which was torn apart in the World War. Now, it dedicates maximum resources to development, saving the expenditure which would otherwise have gone to war.

Comment: "Obviously." I meant about the gifts of the holy spirit being on equal footing. That's the assumption that underlies your question. If that's not a new thing, then your question doesn't make sense. A further consideration would be whether the "peace" in the greeting is entirely synonymous with the fruit of the spirit.

Comment: 'Peace' is NOT listed in the Gifts of the Holy Spirit. One could argue that Peace encompasses all the Seven Gifts of the Spirit. But my take is that the Peace Greeting during the liturgy owes its origin to the ancient times when every other Gift, say Fortitude and Knowledge,  depended on the existence of Peace which had more of external traits .

Comment: Peace is a fruit of the Spirit though. You have still provided no clear reason why anything has changed theologically so that gifts of the spirit should be mentioned instead of peace. Perhaps you should first ask why peace is there at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not at home in the English translation of the liturgy, could you please state what Latin words at what place in the liturgy you think the Church should or might consider replacing?

Even without knowing what it is you exactly mean, I can give a general answer:

The Church has known several liturgical reform movements, and in 2000 years, given the number of Catholics, statistically you can be almost certain that any change in the liturgy must have been considered by some Catholics at some time. Maybe even a pope, a church teacher, an apostolic father, and so on.

But you ask if *the church* has considered this specific change. For context I think one should read [Sacrosanctum Concilium, The Constitution on the Sacred Liturgy by the Second Vatican Council](https://www.vatican.va/archive/hist_councils/ii_vatican_council/documents/vat-ii_const_19631204_sacrosanctum-concilium_en.html). Paragraph 4 gives an indication to how the Church looks at the liturgy, and changes to any of the lawful rites: all reform must be seen “in the light of sound tradition”. A bit further it is explained that the liturgy is always an exercise of the priest Jesus Christ and of His Body, the Church.

This together may give some idea about how holy the liturgy is, but more, how much it is “from Christ”.

In paragraph 21 it explains how the liturgy has elements that can never be changed, and elements that must be changed according to the times.

I will not try to summarise the entire document, but it is very interesting reading material. It will give you an idea about the importance of the liturgy to the Church, and the great care that the Church takes in any reform of it.

What you should read in this document, I think, is that the liturgy is *not* something that is to be changed at will. Most of it is not to be changed at all, but it still is a temporal form of an eternal meaning. The temporal form can, may, and even must be adjusted to the times if it is necessary to convey the eternal meaning because the understanding of the people is always changing. But it is impossible to change the eternal meaning, because it is Jesus Christ who conveys that meaning, who is the priest and presbyter of the liturgy.

The catholic faith is not a matter of what we, as the Church, the body of Christ, are inclined to conclude, but of the eternal truth of the head of the Church, Jesus Christ. We may conclude that something is better fitting in the modern world, that something could better be replaced with something else, but that cannot be. And as we believe, we pray, *lex orandi, lex credendi*, we pray as we believe. The liturgy is eternal in what we believe as it is the highest form of our prayer.

So the chances that the Church has considered what you ask, especially based on the arguments you give, are small. As I said, I don’t know the English translation of the liturgy well enough to see what exactly you think might be reconsidered, but I have tried to find any evidence of *the Church*, in an ecumenical council, considering changes of the kind you refer to, and I haven’t found any.

That doesn’t mean it didn’t happen, it only means I could find it, and I don’t expect to find it.

Comment: Thanks, ABM K. In the Latin  and Syro Malabar rites of liturgy which I attend, one frequently comes across the prayer for peace and the salutation which the faithful need to make to one another , saying Peace Be With You. In the Syro Malabar rite, the Altar Boys or Girls are required to repeat over and over, a request  to the faithful saying " Let us pray; peace be with us ". This works as an interlude between the prayers said by the celebrant. Hope you attend the Lain rite of liturgy.

Comment: In Latin it is "Pax vobis"

Comment: I may be looking in the wrong way, but “pax vobis” isn’t part of the Novo Ordo, as far as I can find.

There is a “oremus” (let us pray), but not followed by anything I would translate as “peace be with us”. 

Is this about the part “Pax Domini sit semper vobiscum.

Et cum spiritu tuo.
”?

Comment: @ABMK In both Novus Ordo and Traditional rite, the "pax vobis" is reserved to prelates (bishops, abbots)

Comment: So, either the English translation is not correct, or the question is about a very specific liturgy, or I don’t understand the question.

Comment: I am most used to the Novus Ordo, but also to the Tridentine Mass. There is enough “peace” in them, but not in the form you mention it, at least not in the Latin version I know, or I am not looking right. That is possible, but why don’t you just show me what it is you exactly mean?

Comment: Novus Ordo and Tridentine are but texts of the same Latin ( also called Roman) Rite Liturgy. Oriental rites follow distinctly separate texts of prayers , even though the basic structure of the Mass is the same across all rites. All the Catholic rites including the oriental ones, have due approval of the Holy See .

Comment: To give you an illustration, the English text of the Holy Mass in Roman ( Latin) rite ends with the celebrant saying " The Mass is ended; go in peace ".

Comment: Ah, the “ite missa est”. One would translate this with something like “The Offer is done” (but better English, no doubt). There is no mentioning of peace there. But I do know that in Dutch, we use the same translation: you all go in peace now. I do not know, or have researched, why this has entered the translation.

Comment: ABM K, now that you have understood my Question, hope you will come up with your views, in your capacity of a member of the clergy.

Comment: Well, my answer still stands: the liturgy is not that easy to change, and it shouldn’t be. You may find it should, but it isn’t yours. Any changes on the temporal are only needed and called for if the eternal is no longer understood. So my answer to your question still is: no, the Church hasn’t, and probably will not, consider the kind of changes you think to be in order.